# Hierarchy of MQTT topics for publishing 3 data points

Tags: hierarchy, mqtt, publish-subscribe, data-integrity

This is a compound issue regarding MQTT topics.

I have several MQTT clients (sensor nodes) that are publishing Sensed Data as "_data", Signal Strength as "_rssi" and time of data collection "_toc" to their three topics.

> /node/node_id/data/
>   /node/node_id/rssi/
>   /node/node_id/toc/

where "node_id" is an identifier (integer/numeral) for a client (node) (unique for a node). The *respective payloads* are **_data** (floating point data), **_rssi** (floating point) and **_toc** (Unix datetime). Clearly, all the three data points are related to one another.

This design helps in maintaining Access Control to different subscribers based on topics they are authorized to subscribe.

However, there is one thing of great concerning with using 3 different topics per node/client - If the connection between MQTT client and server gets broken (is lost) right after publishing "data" payload and before publishing the "rssi" and "timestamp" payloads, then is a mismatch between the three data points, message from the "data" topic would reflect new value while the other two topics would be holding the older values ~ loss of integrity.

I could use a one-liner topic like

> /node/node_id/data/_data/rssi/_rssi/toc/_toc

Or

> /node/node_id/(_data,_rssi,_toc)

And replace, _data, _rssi and _toc with corresponding values, and parse it and separate the values. The last topic style, particularly, reduces the number of times a client will be publishing - saving on data cost and integrity errors. It is also short in length. But, of course, this is messy, very ad-hoc in nature and errors can easily leap in.

Could someone suggest a middle way to always have data integrity and minimize the number of publishing a client should do, and also maintain clean message structure. I would definitely prefer to have data integrity but would also want to segregate access rights between subscribers.

Comment: Are you saying that out of the set of measurements (you give 3 above: _data, _rssi and _toc) certain subscribers are allowed to only see subsets (eg. _data and _toc vs. _rssi and _toc vs. all three)? It seems you don't want your sensor nodes in charge of your access control. From a design standpoint, allow only one subscriber to have full access to the raw measurements, then partition that data and re-publish subsets according to access rights.

Comment: @GambitSupport yes, very much so; the actual network architecture is a bit intricate with many components in play. Re-publishing looks like a great solution; it solves all the 3 architectural concerns - Integrity, Access Control, low data transmission costs. Amazingly simple solution that escaped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do not encode the data into topics, it will end up really really messy and mean you have to use really nasty wildcard subscriptions to make things work.

If the data really needs to be tied together that closely then the only option is to publish a single message with all 3 values in the payload. This does mean you can't separate access to the individual components, but it is the only way.

Comment: You sir have seen things apparently. It didn't even come to my mind that OP is encoding the data _in the topic_ ...

Comment: Of course, I will not be putting data into topic. Going to use the solution provided by @gambit by putting all the data in one single topic as a payload and then parsing it further. Thanks for your reply.